# QGIS how to troubleshoot few SVG symbols that are displayed as a question mark?

Tags: qgis

I created SVG symbols for points and pathed them correctly. When I export the project to test locally some points show up as a question mark symbol. I made sure the paths were correctly assigned and still have this issue. I selected the question marks and found that its a random few that have this issue. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: I currently am "hardcoding" paths by data defined override in order to avoid repeated fixing of paths gone missing.

Comment: Hi there Erik, interesting! Can you expand on "hardcoding" paths please?

Comment: I suggest you read up on data defined override.